# Pg_repack table without unique key

Tags: postgresql, unique-key

I have below issue:
I have a table, of course on a prod... Sometime before we faced with limit of INT pk, so we just modify it as -1 as default.
Now I want to run pg_repack on it, but this needs to have not NULL and unique key on it.
Do you have any experience with that?
My options:
1. Vacuum full. Cannot, because 
impact.
2. Add some additional unique column, can take some time and impact. Also can broke select * queries.
3. Add column with default value, then update with serial and mark as unique. Never tried that before.
AWS RDS.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a performance impact, your goal is to keep `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks as short as possible.

So

- add a `bigint` column without a default value
- create a sequence `OWNED BY` the new column
- use `ALTER TABLE` to set a default value for the column using the sequence
- update the NULL values in the new column from the sequence

  You should do that in batches to avoid locking too many rows at once.
- create a unique index on the new column `CONCURRENTLY`
- add a unique constraint using the new index

That will not give you a primary key, because you are still missing the `NOT NULL` constraint. There is no way to set the column `NOT NULL` without scanning the entire table, which will hold an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock for a longer time.
However, if you need a true primary key, you cannot avoid that.

Here is my procedure in SQL using a sample table:

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD id bigint;

CREATE SEQUENCE x_id_seq OWNED BY x.id;

ALTER TABLE x ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('x_id_seq');

UPDATE x SET id = nextval('x_id_seq')
WHERE id IS NULL
  AND somecol BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;
UPDATE x SET id = nextval('x_id_seq')
WHERE id IS NULL
  AND somecol BETWEEN 10001 AND 20000;
...

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY x_id_idx ON x(id);

ALTER TABLE x ADD UNIQUE USING INDEX x_id_idx;
```

I hope that next time you know better, and you'll never again create a table without a primary key.

Comment: If You use postgres 12 and up, You can add : "alter table x add check (id not null) not valid; alter table x validate constraint x_id_check; alter table x add primary key using index x_id_idx;".
Postgres 12 and up will skip full table scan when set not null column if there are already not null constraint check on that column. So, adding primary key will be minimum locking.